# iterating through a list with a function that relates list objects

Tags: python, list, pandas, iteration

Let's say I have a list:

```
stuff = ['Dogs[1]','Jerry','Harry','Paul','Cats[1]', 'Toby','Meow','Felix']
```

Is it possible to iterate through the list and assign the animal name to the animal in a dataframe format like:

```
Animal    Name
Dog       Jerry
Dog       Harry
Dog       Paul
Cat       Toby... etc
```

by iterating through the list

```
for i in stuff:
    if '1' in i:
        new_list.append(i)...
```

I have been exhaustively searching how to do this but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use first `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':stuff})
print (df)
      Name
0  Dogs[1]
1    Jerry
2    Harry
3     Paul
4  Cats[1]
5     Toby
6     Meow
7    Felix
```

Then [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) new column `Animal` with [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) values with `[1]` and last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df.insert(0, 'Animal', df['Name'].str.extract('(.*)\[1\]', expand=False).ffill())
df = df[df['Animal'].duplicated()].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  Animal   Name
0   Dogs  Jerry
1   Dogs  Harry
2   Dogs   Paul
3   Cats   Toby
4   Cats   Meow
5   Cats  Felix
```

Another possible solution with mask created by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
df.insert(0, 'Animal', df['Name'].str.extract('(.*)\[1]', expand=False).ffill())
df = df[~df['Name'].str.contains('\[1]')].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  Animal   Name
0   Dogs  Jerry
1   Dogs  Harry
2   Dogs   Paul
3   Cats   Toby
4   Cats   Meow
5   Cats  Felix
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a dataframe from lists of dicts. So something like

```
dicts = []
animal = ""
for i in stuff:
    if '1' in i:
        animal = i[:-3]
    else:
        dicts.append({'Name': i, 'Animal': animal}
pd.DataFrame(dicts)
```

This (and any other solution I can imagine) is really fragile, though. You had better be certain of the format of your input.